# Is it possible to get the directory path of pipelines in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

When I create a new pipeline in Azure DevOps I can sort within folders in the pipelines section:

[image]

Is it possible to get the directory path during pipeline execution?

For example, if I want to run the `app-libs-few-artifact_angular` pipeline, I would like to get the path where  is located ("Canales Digitales/demo/app-libs-few-artifact_angular").

Answer (score 0):

You can get with [Pipelines - Get Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

In the response you get the pipeline folder:

[image]

So add a script in your pipeline that get it from the api.